# $.ajax logs red errors even though .fail is being used

Tags: ajax, promise

I have a generic function for getting some text data, and it uses $.ajax to try and get this data from several possible locations. This function contains a promise which is returned and is used in later code in various ways among which is pushing several of these results into an array and processing them with `Promise.all`.
It seems to be going well except for the fact that on some of the items I am getting some red dev console errors - although I'm using a .fail function which supposedly should catch these errors and prevent the red text from appearing in the console.

```
function getDataText(url, type, locationKey, dataName){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            dataType : type,
            timeout: 500
        }).fail((err) => {
            console.log(`getDataText(): REJECTED!\t${url}`);
            reject(new Error(`Could not get '${url}' from location ${locationKey}`));
        }).done((data) => {
            console.log(`getDataText(): RESOLVED!\t${url}`);
            resolve({ data : data, path : url });
        });
    });
}
```

What it does is log the red errors first and then it says my "REJECTED" message on the next line. What I'm expecting is no red text at all because I'm supposed to be catching them - my "REJECTED" message should be enough I think.

Is this normal, or am I missing something?

I will also add: *this does not happen for all of the rejected items*! It happens for exactly these two:

- A CORS policy-blocked file, where the URL is a local path starting with "C:..." which is expected at the location for which this is at.
- A 404 non-found error for a Mac file-path starting with "/Volumes/" where the ajax request automatically prepends the "http://localhost" part because as I'm running this on my localhost, and it thinks the file will start from there (this was used when testing on simple local HTML file as opposed to served).

Interestingly the rejected items which do not have the red error are both files which were located on other computers and started with "http://[network IP address]". I am wondering if there's not something simple which could be done to help catch those first two...